# how to set an initial value for an entity attribute in Jhipster JDL?

Tags: jhipster

Is there a way to set the initial number of votes (assignedVotesPoints) of my entity (ProposalUser) to let's say 100 when the entity is created using JDL?

```
entity ProposalUser {
    creationDate Instant required,
    assignedVotesPoints Long
}
```

I know I could modify the Spring part to somehting like:

private Long assignedVotesPoints = 100L;

But I would like to do it using JDL.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not possible currently, feel free to propose a feature request on github though it might be rejected due to policy 2 https://www.jhipster.tech/policies/#-policies

It would have more chances to be accepted if you propose to contribute code that implements it.

Comment: I wish I could, but it looks like money is not enough even for importante features that are not currently working: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/9605 . Thanks for your help, Gaël

Comment: Time is more important than money for sure